# How to Install YUM on Cent OS 5.8

Tags: unix, installation, centos, rpm, yum

I managed to uninstall it by accident. I have found the package yum-3.2.22-39.e15.centos.noarch.rpm and when I try to install it says Failed dependencies:

yum-fastestmirror is needed by yum-3.2.22-39.el5.centos.noarch

So I got that and tried installing that and I get more failed dependencies:

rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch
        yum >= 3.0 is needed by yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch

How do I install YUM quickly and properly without the dependency issues that keep coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/install-yum-934200/

Make sure you add the nodep flag when installing the fast mirrors on RPM.